# iOS client for Kurento tutorials

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, kurento

I'm trying to get an iOS client running one of the Kurento tutorials, e.g. this one: https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-hello-world. I haven't been able to find a lot about Kurento on iOS, other than the [Kurento-iOS](https://github.com/nubomediaTI/Kurento-iOS) framework, which doesn't have a lot of documentation.

I have tried implementing NBMWebRTCPeerDelegate based on the documentation, but it doesn't say anything about actually streaming video and I can't get it to build. Does anyone know how to get a basic application running or know of any sample code?

Comment: Did you find something useful? I'm trying to use the Kurento iOS SDK for making a one2one video call, or some code to use from it to make the iOS client for this:

http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-one2one-adv.html

Comment: @Objectif I never managed to, sorry. I ended up using AppRTC for what I was doing.

Comment: Ah, I see, I stumbled upon AppRTC as well. It worked fine from what I tried, but it does not offer the ability to record the video call (which is what I need). Correct me if I'm wrong about this (the recording feature), since you have experience with AppRTC, I would very much like to be wrong on this :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than sing Kurento , you should go for ErizoClient iOS
, it have full documentation for server configuration and also for client side,

for ios client : 
["Github Repo for Erizo Client iOS"](https://github.com/zevarito/Licode-ErizoClientIOS)

For documentation you can follow this link :

[Documentation for Erizo Client](http://lynckia.com/licode/architecture.html)

[Demo Video Conferencing Rooms for Testing](http://chotis2.dit.upm.es/)
 You can setup your own server for remote and localhost on Mac or ubuntu
[Server Installation](http://lynckia.com/licode/install.html)